# route not found even if it exist php leaf framework

Tags: php, leaf

When I run the project on my localhost the routes work perfectly but when I export to shared hosting it keeps giving {"data": "Resource not found", "code":404} according to the 404 configurations in the Route/index.php

I've hosted a previous project using this framework and it still works to this moment, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong for this particular project. I've crossed checked the previous project config with this one and there's no difference.

This is the content of my .env file

```
    APP_NAME=LEAF_API
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:AUAyDriQD1kFdIbwTHlnCm2pYn+qxDBa55SFwB9PUzg=
    APP_DOWN=false
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://localhost

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=9jafood
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
    DB_CHARSET=utf8
    DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

    PROD_SERVER=hello
    PROD_PORT=22
    PROD_USER=leaf
    APPLICATION_DIR=leaf
    APPLICATION_PATH=leaf
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews -Indexes
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

This the index file that the .htaccess file rewrites to

```
  <?PHP

  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  \Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__)->load();

  require __DIR__ . "/Config/bootstrap.php";

  require __DIR__ . "/Config/functions.php";

  Leaf\View::attach(\Leaf\Blade::class);

  $app = new Leaf\App(AppConfig());

  $app->evadeCors(false);

  require __DIR__ . "/App/Routes/index.php";

  $app->run();
```

This is my index.php file located in the Route folder

```
    <?php

    /**@var Leaf\App $app */

    $app->set404(function () {
     json("Resource not found", 404, true);
    });

    $app->setErrorHandler(function ($e = null) use($app) {
     if ($e) {
      if ($app->config("log.enabled")) {
         $app->logger()->error($e);
      }
    }

    json("An error occured, our team has been notified", 500, true);
    });

    $app->setNamespace("\App\Controllers");

    require __DIR__ . "/_route.php";
```

This is my route.php

```
   <?php

   $app->group("/merchant", function () use ($app) {
       $app->post("/", "VendorsController@index");
       $app->get("/delivery/{id}", "VendorsController@cost");
       $app->get("/category/{id}", "CategoriesController@index");
   });

   $app->group("/meal", function () use ($app) {
       $app->get("/", "MealsController@index");
       $app->post("/search", "MealsController@search");
       $app->post("/search/location", "MealsController@searchBasedOnLocation");
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be really late considering the date, but I just noticed you are requiring a `_route.php` file but your file name looks like `route.php`.

Also you can post your questions on the leaf forum on GitHub as well so they can be resolved quickly.